# How to translate 'grade school 風紀/風紀員' into English?

Tags: translation

When I was a grade school student in Hong Kong, some students in school would be assigned positions of  duty or authority. For example, 班長 (class representative) , 行長 (roll leader) and 風紀(whose duty is to maintain order in teachers' stead, for example, keeping peace during recess, help maintaining order in morning speech etc.)

I can't find a translation of 風紀 in this context and  Google translates 風紀員 as "discipline officer". I wonder is it appropriate to call a student 'officer'

Should I translate 風紀 in this context as 'student discipline officer' or 'student discipline team member? If there's an existing official translation, please let me know

[image]

Comment: isn’t it called “prefect”?

Comment: I never heard of it

Comment: you’re kidding :) they wore a “prefect” badge in school. ok, read harry potter: the order of the phoenix, which had plot that ron, hermione & draco were assigned as perfects.

Comment: never been in grade school outside of Hong Kong, never read/ watch harry potter. Now you know I don't have kid

Comment: btw, the top of these little “licensed rogues” is named “head prefect” :(

Comment: I've heard the term ["hall monitor"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDSaG.jpg).  We didn't really have these where I went to school (in Australia).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official term is indeed prefect.

See https://www.ccss.edu.hk/discipline/prefect.htm  <--- see URL?

學校風紀員：
被選為風紀是學生的一種榮譽。學期初於中三、中四及中五級各班，由班主任或訓導老師提名，挑選一些嚴守紀律及品行良好之同學，經訓導組審議通過，加以培訓，以執行當值職務。服務表現良好的 風紀，學年結束時獲服務獎狀或加操行分以資獎勵。

School Prefect:

To be selected as prefect is an honour. In the beginning of school in grades 9, 10, or 11, teachers and grade administrators will nominate candidates from well-disciplined students who obey the rules, with approval from the guidance committee, to receive additional training, to execute the new duties. The prefects who carry out their duty of diligence will receive service awards or bonus behaviral grade points as reward.

Comment: When Hong Kong had the  high school entrance exam, only grade 5 students would be chosen as prefect in grade school. Grade 6 students need more time to study for that exam. My high school (grade 7- 12) did not have prefect. I don't know about other high school

Comment: The linked page in this answer is from a specific school 香港道教聯合會青松中學, so obviously some high school do have prefect, unlike mine

Comment: Querying for the word in relation to HK shows that many schools have similar setups for grades 3 4 and 5. Though it's clearly not a ministry of education requirement.

Answer (score 1):

It's called "prefect".

not "perfect" of course :-)

Answer (score 0):

水巷孑蠻 wrote: isn’t it called “prefect”

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prefect

> 3. a student monitor in a usually private school

So, it can be called “prefect” or "student monitor"

Thanks, 水巷孑蠻